# python string encoding error

Tags: python, string, encoding

I am using python3 to call a function written in another language. The function returns a string which should be a Chinese character. But I only get a string which is b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee', not the Chinese character I am expecting. How do I convert it back to the character I wanted? Thanks.

Update:  the code is

```
temp=ts.RemoteCallFunc("StockIndexFutures_basis",["IF00","SH000300",ts.EncodeDate(2012,3,7),ts.EncodeDate(2012,5,1),"日线"],{});
```

and the result is a list :

[{b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee': 7.313000000000102,
  b'SH000300': 2631.487,
  b'date': b'2012-04-26',
  b'IF00': 2638.8},
 {b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee': 12.442999999999756,
  b'SH000300': 2626.157,
  b'date': b'2012-04-27',
  b'IF00': 2638.6}]

Comment: Which encoding do you except your text to be? It doesn't look like UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the byte string `b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee'` to the proper characters, you can call `decode` on the byte string and specify one of [standard codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). For example:

```
x = b'\xbb\xf9\xb2\xee'
x.decode('gbk')  # gbk is listed as the "unified Chinese" codec

'基差'
```

I'm just guessing on the codec and you may want to experiment with that.

It's not clear which Python 3.x version you're using, so I tested this with Python 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, and 3.4 and the results are the same for all versions.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for.